# The table doesn't fit in the center or left side on the page?

Tags: tables

I try to fit the following table on a page, but there is a lot of space on the left, and it doesn't fit in the center. Any suggestion please?

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \resizebox{0.72\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
        \caption{\textbf{The first five embryonic developmental stages of \emph{Drosophila}} \citep{campos}}
  \label{table: fly stages}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
   \hline
Stages & Age in minute & Developmental progresses \\ 
\hline
    1 & 0-15 & Pronuclear fusion \\ 
\hline
 2 & 15-70 & Preblastoderm (mitotic cycles 1-9) - early cell division - start of cleavage \\ 
\hline
 3 & 70-90 & Pole bud formation - nuclear division 9 \\ 
\hline
 4 & 90-130 & Syncytial blastoderm (mitotic cycles 10-13) - end of cleavage divisions \\ 
\hline
 5 & 130-180 & Cellularization of the blastoderm \\ 
\hline

  \end{tabular}

      \end{minipage}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist on your method, do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,showframe,natbib}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h]
  \centering
    \caption[]{\footnotesize\textbf{The first five embryonic developmental stages of \emph{Drosophila}} \citep{campos}}
  \label{table: fly stages}
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
   \hline
Stages & Age in minute & Developmental progresses \\
\hline
    1 & 0-15 & Pronuclear fusion \\
\hline
 2 & 15-70 & Preblastoderm (mitotic cycles 1-9) - early cell division - start of cleavage \\
\hline
 3 & 70-90 & Pole bud formation - nuclear division 9 \\
\hline
 4 & 90-130 & Syncytial blastoderm (mitotic cycles 10-13) - end of cleavage divisions \\
\hline
 5 & 130-180 & Cellularization of the blastoderm \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}%
  }%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember that there is also `adjustbox` package which provides `center` and `max width` keys for the same job.

This is what I would do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe,natbib}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h]  
  \centering
    \caption[]{The first five embryonic developmental stages of \emph{Drosophila} \citep{campos}}
  \label{table: fly stages}
    \begin{tabular}{|C{0.1\textwidth}|
                     C{0.2\textwidth}|
                     C{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-6\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
   \hline
Stages & Age in minute & Developmental progresses \\
\hline
    1 & 0-15 & Pronuclear fusion \\
\hline
 2 & 15-70 & Preblastoderm (mitotic cycles 1-9) - early cell division - start of cleavage \\
\hline
 3 & 70-90 & Pole bud formation - nuclear division 9 \\
\hline
 4 & 90-130 & Syncytial blastoderm (mitotic cycles 10-13) - end of cleavage divisions \\
\hline
 5 & 130-180 & Cellularization of the blastoderm \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Harish- Thanks. but it appears very big. Is there any way to make it smaller?

Comment: @Maryam Use `\resizebox{0.7\textwidth}{!}{%` or any size you like.

Comment: @ Harish- I did it, but caption is too big even though I use \small

Comment: @Maryam You may use `\footnotesize` or `\tiny` etc. See the edited answer. But this will destroy consistency though.

Comment: @HarishKumar - I'm glad you figured out what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I undertand what you mean by saying that the table doesn't fit in the center or left-hand side of the page. I suggest you load the `tabularx` package and use a `tabularx` environment instead of `tabular`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,natbib}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{\textbf{The first five embryonic developmental stages of \emph{Drosophila}} \citep{campos}}
  \label{table: fly stages}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|C|}
   \hline
Stages & Age in minutes & Developmental progresses \\ 
\hline
    1 & 0--15 & Pronuclear fusion \\ 
\hline
 2 & 15--70 & Preblastoderm (mitotic cycles 1--9) -- early cell division -- start of cleavage \\ 
\hline
 3 & 70--90 & Pole bud formation -- nuclear division 9 \\ 
\hline
 4 & 90--130 & Syncytial blastoderm (mitotic cycles 10--13) -- end of cleavage divisions \\ 
\hline
 5 & 130--180 & Cellularization of the blastoderm \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do the same thing with other tables, but all fit in the center except this one which is wider.

Comment: @Maryam - As mentioned earlier, I don't know what "fit in the center" means. If you want the `tabularx` environment to take up, say, `0.8\textwidth`, that's fine; just add a `\centering` instruction before `\begin{tabularx}`.

Comment: @ Mico- Thanks, I mean in the pdf version the table goes to the most right hand side.

Comment: @ Micro Thanks but even with 0.7\textwidth seems too big, and not very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code couldn't work: you wrote `\` instead of `\\` at end of rows. Moreover, you don't need to use `\resizebox`: just use `small` at the beginning of the table, and `tabularx`. I also replaced the hyphens with endashes and loaded the `caption` package to have the right vertical spacing between caption and table body, and the `cellspace` to have a minimal vertical spacing at the top and the bottom of rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}

\usepackage[showframe,nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font = {bf, small}}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering \small%
\caption{The first five embryonic developmental stages of \emph{Drosophila}}\label{table: fly stages}
\begin{tabularx}{0.72\linewidth}{|c|c|S{X}|}
\hline
Stages & Age in minute & Developmental progresses \\
\hline
1 & 0--15 & Pronuclear fusion \\
\hline
2 & 15--70 & Preblastoderm (mitotic cycles 1-9) -- early cell division -- start of cleavage \\
\hline
3 & 70--90 & Pole bud formation -- nuclear division 9 \\
\hline
4 & 90--130 & Syncytial blastoderm (mitotic cycles 10-13) -- \linebreak end of cleavage divisions \\
\hline
5 & 130--180 & Cellularization of the blastoderm \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a layout that's more like the one you obtain with your code, here is a way to go. Note that the use of `resizebox` results in the caption font smaller than the main body font, at the cost of a more complex code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}

\usepackage[showframe,nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font = {bf, scriptsize}}

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering \scriptsize%
\caption{The first five embryonic developmental stages of \emph{Drosophila}}\label{table: fly stages}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|Sc|}%{0.72\linewidth}
\hline
Stages & Age in minute & Developmental progresses \\
\hline
1 & 0--15 & Pronuclear fusion \\
\hline
2 & 15--70 & Preblastoderm (mitotic cycles 1-9) --- early cell division --- start of cleavage \\
\hline
3 & 70--90 & Pole bud formation --- nuclear division 9 \\
\hline
4 & 90--130 & Syncytial blastoderm (mitotic cycles 10-13) --- end of cleavage divisions \\
\hline
5 & 130--180 & Cellularization of the blastoderm \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

With your code:

\begin{table}[h]
\centering\resizebox{0.72\textwidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{\textbf{The first five embryonic developmental stages of \emph{Drosophila}}}%\citep{campos}
\label{table: fly stages}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Stages & Age in minute & Developmental progresses \\
\hline
1 & 0-15 & Pronuclear fusion \\
\hline
2 & 15-70 & Preblastoderm (mitotic cycles 1-9) - early cell division - start of cleavage \\
\hline
3 & 70-90 & Pole bud formation - nuclear division 9 \\
\hline
4 & 90-130 & Syncytial blastoderm (mitotic cycles 10-13) - end of cleavage divisions \\
\hline
5 & 130-180 & Cellularization of the blastoderm \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but What I get with my own codes look very beautiful, except it appears in the most right hand side of the page.

Comment: You still have the problem of centring, the vertical spacing between caption and main body,  and the caption fontsize. Take a look at my new version.

Comment: No thanks, the above answer worked for me. All these are fine, but I wanted to keep just one line for each row in the table.

Comment: Well, you have one line now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a good solution is a paragraph-like, not centered, last column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
        \caption{\textbf{The first five embryonic developmental stages of \emph{Drosophila}} %\citep{campos}
}
  \label{table: fly stages}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{7cm}|}
   \hline
Stages & Age in minute & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Developmental progresses} \\ 
\hline
    1 & 0--15 & Pronuclear fusion \\
\hline
 2 & 15--70 & Preblastoderm (mitotic cycles 1--9) --- early cell division --- start of cleavage \\ 
\hline
 3 & 70--90 & Pole bud formation --- nuclear division 9 \\ 
\hline
 4 & 90--130 & Syncytial blastoderm (mitotic cycles 10--13) --- end of cleavage divisions \\ 
\hline
 5 & 130--180 & Cellularization of the blastoderm \\ 
\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please observe changing hyphens into en-dashes or em-dashes.

I've removed `\minipage` as meaningless in this situation, and `\citep` as inacessible from your snippet.

Comment: Thanks, but It makes it too big. Doesn't look nice at all.